# how to turn pygame.key.get_pressed() into a key

Tags: python, pygame

Doing `print pygame.key.get_pressed()` prints me lots of `0`'s, but is there any way that I can print those `0`'s out as a letter and then sign that letter to a variable?

This is what I mean:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
import time
while True:
    pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    print(pressed) #This prints 0, but I want it to print the button I am pressing
    time.sleep(1)
```

EDIT: I should probaly add that I am working on a scoreboard in pygame and that is why I need to check which button is pressed to be able to enter a name

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list of pressed keys as strings with this piece of code:

```
pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed() # already familiar with that
buttons = [pygame.key.name(k) for k,v in enumerate(pressed) if v]
print(buttons) # print list to console
```

`pygame.key.name()` takes the index of the current list object and returns its name as string. Read more [here](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.name).

**BUT** if you are planning to use this list to test for key presses in your code, I highly recommend you to get familiar with pygames way of handling inputs. You can find a tutorial about that [here](http://www.raspberry-pi-geek.com/Archive/2014/05/Pygame-modules-for-interactive-programs).

Comment: either I'm not getting something or this simply doesn't work for me

Comment: @Adde21_30 which python version are you using? Please append your current code snippet to your question.

Comment: I found a solution to the problem so an answer is not needed anymore. thanks anyways